# call() is not working with getter and setter in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, api, object

```js
let Name = {
   get fullname() {
        return this.fname + this.last
    }
}

function pension() {
    return this.age > 60
}
let firstclass_employee = [{
    fname: "sangeth",
    last: "AV",
    age: 21,
    address: {
        housename: "good house",
        place: "goodplace",
        city: "goodtwon",
        postcode: 121212
    },
    hobbies: ["driving", "travelling", "sports"]
}, {
    fname: "ramu",
    last: "kv",
    age: 29,
    address: {
        housename: "etho veedu",
        place: "vayadi",
        city: "kalur",
        postcode: 11111
    },
    hobbies: ["travelling", "sports"]
}]
console.log(" objects::\t", Name, "\n", firstclass_employee)
    //calling a out side function for an object(out side function may be inside an object oe not)
console.log("Fullname of first employee::", Name.fullname.call(firstclass_employee[0]))
console.log("Pension status of of first emlpoyee::", pension.call(firstclass_employee[0]))
console.log("Fullname of 2nd employee::", Name.fullname.call(firstclass_employee[1]))
console.log("Pension status of of 2nd emlpoyee::", pension.call(firstclass_employee[1]))
```

AND getting error--->
console.log("Fullname of first employee::", Name.fullname.call(firstclass_employee[0]))
                                                          ^

> TypeError: Name.fullname.call is not a function

Comment: Are you trying to create a getter? If so, what you get with `Name.fullname` is what the function returns, not the function itself. If you want a regular function you don't want a getter.

Answer (score 0):

remove `get` - which is not a valid here

```
let Name = {
   fullname() {
        return this.fname + this.last
    }
}
```

Comment: `get` is valid there; it creates a property getter. What's invalid is using `call` on property getter.

Comment: why call() is invalid here,

Answer (score 0):

If you want regular function remove the `get` and it will work fine. Sorry, I was mistakenly said you have errors in the `console.log()` part.

```js
let Name = {
  fullname() {
       return this.fname + this.last
   }
}

function pension() {
   return this.age > 60
}
let firstclass_employee = [{
   fname: "sangeth",
   last: "AV",
   age: 21,
   address: {
       housename: "good house",
       place: "goodplace",
       city: "goodtwon",
       postcode: 121212
   },
   hobbies: ["driving", "travelling", "sports"]
}, {
   fname: "ramu",
   last: "kv",
   age: 29,
   address: {
       housename: "etho veedu",
       place: "vayadi",
       city: "kalur",
       postcode: 11111
   },
   hobbies: ["travelling", "sports"]
}]
console.log(" objects::\t", Name, "\n", firstclass_employee)
//calling a out side function for an object(out side function may be inside an object oe not)
console.log("Fullname of first employee::", Name.fullname.call(firstclass_employee[0]))
console.log("Pension status of of first emlpoyee::", pension.call(firstclass_employee[0]))
console.log("Fullname of 2nd employee::", Name.fullname.call(firstclass_employee[1]))
console.log("Pension status of of 2nd emlpoyee::", pension.call(firstclass_employee[1]))
```

Comment: `console.log` takes an "infinite" number of arguments and echoes each back separated by spaces, so the commas are fine.

Comment: Sorry, it was my bad.

Comment: `console.log()` is widely misused in that sense. When you use `+` to cast objects to strings you lose valuable information.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález @HerecticMonkey Thanks for letting me know some valuable information about  `console.log()`

Answer (score 0):

As far as why the `call()` is invalid is that `Name.fullname` is not exposed as a function. It is exposed the same way as a field would be, e.g.

```
const Name = {
  fullname: 'Bob'
};
```

With that structure, you wouldn't expect to be able to call `Name.fullname.call`, right? But for the purposes of getting the value, that's what the prior code exposed to the outside world (the difference with the field being that you can set the value, whereas with a getter and no setter, the property is read only).

The `get` essentially tells the JavaScript engine that, whenever someone asks for the value of `fullname`, give them the value of the `fname` and `last` properties concatenated together.

Thus, when you ask for `Name.fullname.call(firstclass_employee[0])` it first finds `Name`. Then it asks for the value of `fullname`. It gets back `NaN`, because `this` is the `Name` object and it doesn't have `fname` or `last` properties, and it tries to coerce the first `undefined` (from `this.fname`) to a `Number` for the addition operator, and gets `NaN`. Then it tries to get the `call` function on `NaN`, and there is no such thing, so it throws an error.

---

It appears as though you want to be able to get a full name from any object that has `fname` and `last` properties. I would suggest using static method for that rather than an instance property getter.

Similarly, a static method would work for determining employees who get a pension.

Personally, I would just create a `class` or series of `class`es that I could compose together to bring this functionality together, rather than trying to use `call`, but that's me.

```js
const Name = {
  fullName(obj) {
    return `${obj.fname} ${obj.last}`;
  }
};

const Pay = {
  getsPension(obj) {
    return obj.age > 60;
  }
}

let firstclass_employee = [{
   fname: "sangeth",
   last: "AV",
   age: 21,
   address: {
       housename: "good house",
       place: "goodplace",
       city: "goodtwon",
       postcode: 121212
   },
   hobbies: ["driving", "travelling", "sports"]
}, {
   fname: "ramu",
   last: "kv",
   age: 29,
   address: {
       housename: "etho veedu",
       place: "vayadi",
       city: "kalur",
       postcode: 11111
   },
   hobbies: ["travelling", "sports"]
}]
console.log('should be sangeth AV: ', Name.fullName(firstclass_employee[0]));
console.log('should be false:      ', Pay.getsPension(firstclass_employee[0]));
```

Comment: i already did it without using getter.But i need to know why call() is invalid in my code  with getter